# How can I "Create a new project ... in a different directory using SQL Server BIDS"?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, reporting-services, bids, project-conversion

I attempted to update an SSRS / .rdl project from VS 2005 to VS 2008. It claimed to convert successfully, but then the project stubbornly refuses to make itself available, saying,

> "[project] cannot be opened because its project type (.rptproj) is not
>   supported by this version of the application"

[This post](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/983332) by the purveyors (Microsoft) of the software admits this is a problem. The Resolution given there is:

> To resolve the issue in which you cannot open the project in SQL
>   Server BIDS after you upgrade the project, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Create a new project that has the same name as the original BI project in a different directory by using SQL Server BIDS.
> 2. Add all relevant project items from the upgraded BI project folder. For example, for an Analysis Services project, add the .ds and .dsv
>      files. For a Reporting Services project, add the .rds and .rdl files.
> 3. Save and then open the new BI project.

However, what is meant by the "*by using SQL Server BIDS*" part at the end of step 1? I can easily follow this part: "*Create a new project that has the same name as the original BI project in a different directory*" but when "*by using SQL Server BIDS*" is appended to that, I'm lost - how do I use SQL Server BIDS to create the new project in a different directory? Is that really necessary, or is the "*by using SQL Server BIDS*" portion of the instruction superfluous/misleading?

### UPDATE

Okay, I did that; in VS2008, I created a new project from the Visual Basic > Reporting > Reports Application template. I then created folders (mimicking the existing VS2005 project) named "Reports" and "Shared Data Sources"; finally, I copied over a couple of .rds files into the "Shared Data Sources" folder, and a slew of .rdl files into the "Reports" folder. It compiles. So I guess all is fine. However, creating the project produced a "Form1.vb" file and a "Report1.rdlc" file. There's also a file named "My Project" Are these three files necessary, harmless, or candidates for deletion?

### UPDATE 2

So now I have the .rdl files both in a VS2005 and a VS2008 project; in VS2005, if I 2-click the .rdl file in the Solution Explorer, it opens the design surace but I can right-click and "view code" (XML). In VS2008, if I 2-click the .rdl file, it opens the XML and I see no option to view the "form"...?!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"SQL Server BIDS" is a synonym for Visual Studio (specifically the VS shell and business intelligence project types shipped with SQL Server), therefore this instruction simply means you need to create a new, empty project in Visual Studio of the same type (i.e. Report project) and then add the existing individual rds and rdl files from the original reports project. Adding these files to the project in VS will physically copy them into the new project folder and should result in a new, working project that can be opened with VS.

Comment: Okay, I did that; in VS2008, I created a new project from the Visual Basic > Reporting > Reports Application template. I then created folders (mimicking the existing VS2005 project) named "Reports" and "Shared Data Sources"; finally, I copied over a couple of .rds files into the "Shared Data Sources" folder, and a slew of .rdl files into the "Reports" folder. It compiles. So I guess all is fine. However, creating the project produced a "Form1.vb" file and a "Report1.rdlc" file. There's also a file named "My Project" Are these three files necessary, harmless, or candidates for deletion?

Comment: You are selecting the wrong project type for a Reporting Services project. In File > New > Project you should see a project type called "Business Intelligence Projects" and under that there should be a template called "Report Server Project". This is the one you need to use, you shouldn't end up with .vb files in a reports project.

Comment: If you don't see "Business Intelligence Projects" project type then you need to install Business Intelligence Developer Studio (BIDS) from the SQL Server 2008 installation media. This will install VS shell if not already installed, and add the required project templates.